# loopback: use MapReduce on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, loopbackjs

is it possible to perform MapReduce on a MongoDB by using Loopback? I need this funcionality to be served as a service in my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I find out it's very simple to do this, althought it's a bit undocumented. Given a model `Book` which is using a `mongodb` loopback connector, you can directly connect to the db by

```
var app = require('/server/server.js');
app.models.Book.getDataSource().connector.connect( (err,db) => {});
```

The `db` variable is the very one instantiated by the inner `mongodb` npm module, thus you can perform a map-reduce by the function `db.collection('book').mapReduce`. Docs for this function are [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#mapReduce).